# Unexpected 'as' error PHP

Tags: php, html

Here's the code that's throwing the error:

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach (($content as $table-row): array_map('htmlentities', $table-row)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $table-row);?></td>
</tr>
 <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

And here's the error it is throwing:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS) in /omitted_directory/index.php on line 93

What am I doing wrong here? I've seen this code snippet work for other people on this site....

Comment: You can't use `-` in variables. PHP figures you want to do math. Use an underscore `$table_row`

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's still throwing the error... so....

Comment: It's the colon then `:` that should be a brace `{` and possibly a missing `;`

Comment: what syntax is that for a foreach? With the extra parenthesis and colon inside the loops parameters.

Comment: [**RTFM**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: @user3748554 Have you seen Jonathan's answer and have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the alternative foreach structure with the standard structure. This is how it should look (that is unless there is some new format that I and the manual don't know about):

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($content as $tableRow){ $tableRow=array_map('htmlentities', $tableRow); ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $tableRow);?></td>
</tr>
 <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

---

Plus, you can't use hyphens in variables. PHP figures you want to do math (minus).

- Replace those with an underscore `$table_row` or as one word `$tableRow`

Comment: [Just like I told them too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611335/unexpected-as-error-php#comment47368366_29611335)

Comment: @Fred-ii- it wasn't as simple as just swapping the colon for a curly brace. It wasn't much more, but they had extra parenthesis around parameters in the foreach, a curly brace did exist at the end of the line, they were trying to map inside the foreach definition and their array_map wouldn't do anything unless you saved it back to a variable.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after. Good catch. Let's see what the OP has to say. Let's hope this will solve it for them.